# How to perform action for specific forms in the class of the BaseForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to let my program know which `form` is opened and then do some specific action for that `form`. Forms are opened in a main-window with an overview and the user can click on an image to open a new form. This main-window is not my BaseForm for the forms I want to open.

To check what `form` is open, I tried the following code:

```
bool thisOne;
bool theOtherOne;

private void FormCheck()
{
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (form is frmRectangle)
        {
            thisOne = true;
            theOtherOne = false;
            break;
        }

        if (form is frmCircular)
        {
            theOtherOne = true;
            thisOne = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I set the form-related`booleans` to true, so I can use them in another function, something like this:

```
private void ActionTime()
{
    if (thisOne)
        Debug.WriteLine("ThisOne is open");
        //Do some stuff for the ThisOne form
    if (theOtherOne)
        Debug.WriteLine("TheOtherOne is open");
        //Do some stuff for TheOtherOne form
}
```

ActionTime is called by a `ClickEvent`, but the action never happens... I guess something's going wrong it the `foreach-loop`.

Comment: Who actually calls `ActionTime`?

Comment: @UweKeim I just added it to the question. It's called by a clickevent. When I do a Debug.Writeline("click"); out of the if-statement it works, so ActionTime does it's job

Comment: Is there any way you can tell us what you ***want*** because what you're doing here is a bit convoluted and if we understood what you ***wanted*** we could either fix up this solution or provide another.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli Gheghe, thanks mate, pretty stupid I'd forgotten to call that one! Problem solved!